# Serilog not writing to file on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, serilog

I have deployed a website to a ubuntu machine but unable to get serilog to write to file

Here is what I have:

In Program.cs (omitted unnecessary parts):

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
```

Also:

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder

                .UseUrls($"http://localhost:{port}")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseSerilog();
```

in my appsetting.PreProduction.json:

```
"Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": "Information",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "/var/log/myapp/",
      "rollingInterval": "Day"
    }
  }
]
```

},

This works on my local machine Windows

```
 {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "c:\\myapp\\log.txt",
      "rollingInterval": "Day"
    }
  },
```

Do I need to do anything extra permission wise?

Comment: `"path": "/var/log/myapp/",` doesn't seem right. You need to specify a full path to a file like `/var/log/myapp/myapp.log`

Comment: @abdusco tried that too but no success

Comment: Did you try enabling serilog's self log? https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics

Comment: I added this line after CreateLogger but not sure what to do, or how to continue from there

Comment: Move it before where you set up Serilog, then check the console output for errors. You should see some entries if Serilog is unable to write to a sink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart myapp.service
```

also had to set permissions:

```
mkdir /var/log/myapp/
chown apiuser:apiuser /var/log/myapp/
chmod 740 /var/log/myapp
```

I kept restarting nginx but didn't know I had to restart the service too